# Who was the longest standing Sith Master?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith

I'm not asking who was the oldest in age, or who survived the most years being a practitioner of the Dark Side, but rather which Sith Master was given the *embarrassing burden* of living the longest while having an apprentice or multiple apprentices. Sidious had Vader under his wing for 20+ years, and this seems like a long time given that the end result **must  always be** that the self-centered apprentice rise up and kill their Master--gaining all the power and status--much to their Master's dark desires.

**So which Sith Master had the longest-lasting mentorship? Legends answers are acceptable, as I don't think there's enough new canon to really pull from.**

There's [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/120297/75000) in case anyone needs a refresher on the recorded Master/apprentice pairings. For the cases where there was a tie, multiple apprentices (trained in secret or outside of/before Bane's Order) or the Master actually won (the list in the link shows this rarely, if ever, happens), the years spent with all apprentices should be added up with the first one for the grand total.

Comment: Would Sidious' mentorship of Maul be included in that time? In canon we don't know if Plagueis was still alive while Maul was Sidious' apprentice (i.e. if Sidious was the Sith Master). In Legends we know that Plagueis was still alive until Sidious became Supreme Chancellor.

Comment: It sounds like you're limiting the timeframe to Bane's Sith Order? Or are you including the Sith before Bane (e.g. the Brotherhood of Darkness)?

Comment: If Legends says he was alive, that would mean Sidious was not a Master at the time, and that the training of Maul was not official. I suppose since that would fit in with the Dark Side meta rules (be selfish and find loopholes), I would count it. At least unofficially for now.

Comment: From what I understand there ins't much known before Bane's order, but if there's something there, it would most certainly count

Comment: There's a lot more info in Legends about the [Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith/Legends) both before and after Bane's Order. My answer you linked to only concerns Bane's Order. Sith outside of Bane's Order also don't follow the one-to-one Master/apprentice rule, so I guess you'd be looking for the length of the reign of the leading Sith (if such a Sith existed -- it depends on the structure of the Order at that time)?

Comment: It appears I didn't do deep enough research before posting my question, but yes, the "leading" Sith would be the one taking the credit for (all) the mentoring done

Comment: Also are you looking for consecutive years if being master over one apprentice, or are you including total number of years having an (not necessarily unique) apprentice?

Comment: If multiple apprentices, then the years should be added up

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Legends

Outside of Bane's Order (which was the only Sith Order that followed the Rule of Two), **the longest reigning Sith Master was the [Sith Emperor Tenebrae (also known as Vitiate and Valkorion)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_Emperor), who reigned over the Sith Empire for over 1300 years ([4980 BBY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/4980_BBY) to [3630 BBY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/3630_BBY)).**

Within Bane's Order, the *known* length of time for each Sith Master's reign is as follows:

- Darth Bane: 20 years. Bane was the Sith Master from 1000 BBY (starting with the [Seventh Battle of Ruusan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Seventh_Battle_of_Ruusan)) until his [death by Darth Zannah in 980 BBY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Bane/Legends).
- Darth Tenebrous: 100 years. [Tenebrous killed his Master in 167 BBY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis/Legends#cite_note-Birthyear-1) and was [killed by Darth Plagueis in 67 BBY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/67_BBY).
- Darth Plagueis: 35 years. His reign began in 67 BBY and ended with [his death at the hands of Darth Sidious in 32 BBY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/32_BBY).
- Darth Sidious: 36 years (starting from the death of Plagueis in 32 BBY), longer if you include the time of Sidious' mentorship of Maul (we don't know what year that began). [Sidious' reign ended in 4 ABY at the Battle of Endor.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Endor)

**Darth Tenebrous had the longest known reign of the Sith Masters in Bane's Order. However, we do not know how long many of the other Sith Masters in Bane's Order reigned, so it's possible Tenebrous was not the longest reigning.**

### Canon

There is insufficient information to answer using strictly canon information. We don't know how long each Sith Master reigned (not even Sidious, because we don't know from canon when he killed Plagueis).

Comment: Wow. And I was thinking that 20 years was taking too long. I'm guessing that during Vitiate's rule the main goal of a Master wasn't to be killed by their underlings?

Comment: @SonOfSam The Sith Empire under Vitiate did not follow the Rule of Two -- there were many, many Sith Lords at that time. (Vitiate comes from the video game *The Old Republic*, and players can play as a Sith Lord -- hence the Sith Empire consists of hundreds of Sith Lords.)

Comment: That's super cool. I'm gonna look more into this now.

Comment: @SonOfSam  -  Vitiate may as well be the coolest Emperor ever. I suggest you take a look at *Star Wars: The Old Republic* trailers, in their release order. Absolute coolness.

Comment: @Gallifreian I didn't think the Emperor ever showed up in the trailers. That was Darth Malgus in the trailers.

Comment: @CBredlow He's in the later trailers (as Valkorian), relating to the Eternal Empire. For example, the [Sacrifice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nzq9epS2b1A) and [Betrayed](https://youtu.be/LbpDxrew4A0) trailers.

Comment: @Null I should pick up swtor again, that sounds cool.